# Как парсить объект, значение которого массив?

Tags: java, android, json

Есть полученные данные JSON: `{"code":200, "lang":"en-ru", "text":["какой-то текст"]}`. 
Как вытащить значение "text", если он массив?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    String json= " {\"code\":200, \"lang\":\"en-ru\", \"text\":[\"какой-то текст\"]}";
    try {
        JSONObject rootJson = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(json));
        JSONArray textJson =  rootJson.getJSONArray("text");
        for (int i = 0; i < textJson.length(); i++) {
            Log.d("TAG", textJson.getString(i)); //какой-то текст
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```